# Add node in sorted linked list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make sorted linked list in ascending order , 
but for some reason the code give me one value 
if some one can tell me why I will be thankful
see this function:

```
void AddNode(Node *&head){

        int temp;
        Node *q;
        Node *prev = 0; 
        Node *t;

        cout <<"enter a number : ";
        cin >> temp;
        t = new Node ;
        t->number = temp;
        t->next = 0;

        if (head == 0) {
            head = t;
        } else {
            q = head;
            while (q != 0 ){
                prev = q;

                if(q->number > t->number){
                    prev->next = t;
                    t->next = q;
                    break;  
                }

                q = q->next; // counter     
            }

            if (q == 0 ) // if it is the last value
                q = t;
        }

    }
```

Comment: That parameter?? It smells. Anyway If it compiles then you need to _step-over_ your code to see what is exactly happening. Using F-10 on Visual Studio

Comment: You don't update `head` when the new node is inserted in front. Also, `q = t` at the end doesn't do anything useful - you are updating a local variable but aren't using this new value.

Comment: @FirstStep: What should the OP do if using Eclipse or Code::Blocks?  Maybe the OP should use a *debugger*?  There are other IDEs besides Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Inserting at the end is wrong:

```
if (q == 0 ) // if it is the last value
    q = t;
```

You just modify `q` but never update the link of the last element. You should try:

```
if (q==0) // past end of list
    prev->next = t; // next of last element is t
```

----------EDIT-------------

Your management of pointers through looping is wrong, the following works and should be much clear (only one pointer is used to move in the list):

```
if (head == 0) { // empty list
    head = t;
} else if (t->number < head->number) { // insert in first place
  t->next = head;
  head = t;
} else { // general case
  q = head;
  while (q->next != 0 && q->next->number<t->number) {
    q = q->next;
  }
  cout << "insert after " << q->number << endl;
  t->next = q->next;
  q->next = t;
}
```

Comment: see my new (tested) solution